# Do we need to pay extra fees to create 2 power platform environments?

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, powerapp, licensing, power-platform

We want to create 2 power platform environments; one for testing and the other for production. we need them for developing and deploying to production 2 solutions which contain Power Apps canvas applications, power automate and SharePoint data sources.

I am going to create the 2 environments using a user who have Power Automate premium licenses and who is a power platform admin, and the users who will be using the related power apps and power automate have E1 or E3 licenses... so my question do we need to pay any extra fees for creating and using those 2 environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating additional environments isn't specifically dependent on licensing. But it is dependent on Capacity and the only way to get extra Capacity is to purchase either per user or per app licenses. If all users have are Office licenses then you can also create additional environments using the Developer plan, since those aren't subject to Capacity constraints.

But in your case since you have at least one Premium license you may have the capacity to create multiple environments. Once they are created there is no licensing requirement for the use of apps or flows in those environments.

It is all dependent on the connectors used:

- If you use premium or custom connectors in the app or flow, other users will also need premium licenses.
- If you use standard connections in the app or flow, no need for premium licenses and users should be able to apps with office licenses.

**Reference**: [Do we need to pay extra fees to create 2 power platform environments?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Governance-and/Do-we-need-to-pay-extra-fees-to-create-2-power-platform/m-p/2398990#M10375)